# How to catch the exception of the execute method while using Spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I use the Spring JDBCTemplate to call a stored procedure ,like this

```
Map receive10PrmtBill = (Map) getJdbcTemplate().execute(sql, new CallableStatementCallback() {

        @Override
        public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException,
                DataAccessException {
            cs.setString(1, Constants.ADD_PROC_TYPE);
            Map<String,PrmtBillInfoDatagram> tempMap = new HashMap();

            cs.execute();
```

but the execute method return false and didn't throw any exception ,so I don't know what's wrong with my program , how to catch the Exception? Any help?

This is the proc

```
create proc sp_xx ( @userid int)    
    as   
    begin   
        select personid, personname from person where personid = @userid  

        select teamid, teamname from team   
    end
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with JdbcTemplate. Have you ever read the API of CallableStatement#execute() ? If it is returning false, then it is returning false, and there is no exception for you to handle, that's all

Comment: Thanks first, I just have read the API of CallableStatement#execute() and get what you say.But now, I code like this 
            do{ rs = cs.getResultSet(); 
                updateCount = cs.getUpdateCount(); 
                cs.getMoreResults(); 
              }while(!(rs == null && updateCount == -1));
It always shows that rs == null and updateCount == 1.At the sametime ,I exec the stored procedure in the Sybase, it works OK.It bothers me.

Comment: who knows what's in your stored proc.... have u ever tried to do a simplest stored proc? No one can help u with such information u gave.

Comment: I paste the Proc , it returns muliResultSet, I don't know how to do get all the ResultSet,therefore, I use the JDBCTemplate@AdrianShum

Comment: Try the same code with simpler stored proc with one select only.

Comment: up till now, op still haven't tell what DBMS he is using... sigh.  Anyway, from my very limited memory on JDBC on Oracle, I remember I need to have out param as cursor to return results to caller.  Have a search what is the correct way to do in your DBMS

Comment: I'm very sorry, I'm using Sybase DBMS ,Thanks agian for your help@AdrianShum @Piotr Gwiazda.just now I try to execute the proc using primitive jdbc and It doesn't work either.
simply , the question is that how to get mulitResultSet using jdbcTemplate on Sybase sp

Comment: Working with Sybase might be a hard trip. Do you use jConnect from Sybase or jTDS? Try to switch one driver to another. Try do read driver docs. I have no idea why this does not work. Do stored procedures with one result set work OK?

Comment: I check the project found that we use jConnect,Many people work on this project ,I can't switch the driver. It seems that sp with one resultSet work fine.I will read driver docs.Thanks a lot@PiotrGwiazda

Comment: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource, we use this driver,it seems that there is not much information on it with mulit result Set@PiotrGwiazda, it give me a headache

Comment: I'd just split it into two procedures and wrap two calls in a Java component. You can also try to write a simple class aside that calls the procedure and try to switch drivers there. If you confirm it is a driver issue - split the procedure.

Comment: Look at this discussion: http://www.wmusers.com/forum/showthread.php?21229-Multiple-result-sets-from-Sybase It seems that there is a fix for JDBC driver on empower.softwareag.com. But it's a post from last year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting "IGNORE_DONE_IN_PROC" property to "true". See at:
http://javabob64.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/sybase-and-the-jdbc-driver/

Comment: It's a pity I can't open the web page but I got what you say.I just want it takes effect once,for example I set the property in my java program,because I'm afraid the modify may affect others' program@Piotr Gwiazda

Comment: How do you connect to DB. How do you obtain a `Connection` object? If you can control creating new connection you can set the property for your connection only. Check: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0605/html/prjdbc/prjdbc14.htm and http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0605/html/prjdbc/prjdbc14.htm